# Difference between 'Take' and 'Bring'

Tags: verbs

> 1. Did you **bring** Jack with you?
> 2. Did you **take** Jack with you?

Mike went to the movies with Jack, Samuel called to confirm whether Mike bring/take Jack with him.

Which verb should I pick?

Could you explain to me the differences here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always a difficult one to work out, because it primarily depends on **relative positions** before and after.

In the simplest terms, you **bring it to here**, but **take it to there**.

We are in the pub. Fred arrives. I ask him, "Did you bring Jack with you?"
In effect, "Is Jack here with you **where we both are now**?"

Fred tells me about a trip he went on last week. I ask him, "Did you take Jack with you?"
"Did you & Jack go to a place that is **not here, now**?"

These are the simplest versions.

It gets more 'virtual' or even slightly 'existential' when the place you are talking about isn't 'here now', but will be 'here' by the time the event happens... bear with me...

"Jack, when we go to the park next week, be sure to bring a jacket, in case it rains"

That one is really an edge case, you could actually say 'take' in that circumstance. Either would be understood, but to follow our rule...

Neither you nor Jack are at the park right now, but will be by the time that *finishes happening*. By the time you are both in the park, he will have brought the jacket with him.

When I leave for the park, I'll take my jacket. By the time I get to the park I will have brought it with me.

To use your example...

> Mike went to the movies with Jack. Samuel called to confirm whether Mike **took** Jack with him.

This breaks down to - none of us are there now, so we talk about it as a 'distant location', **there**, so we use **take**.

Answer (score 2):

'**Take someone with you** ' is said when the person saying the sentence is not present at the place of occurring/event , 
And

'**Bring someone with you**' is used when the speaker or questioner is present at the place of event.
In your given example

> 'Samuel called to confirm whether ...'

i.e. Samuel is not present at the place of event that is why it would be 'take' and the modified sentence would be-  'Samuel called to confirm whether Mike took Jack with him.'

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

- bring to the place where the speaker is
- take to the place a speaker is not

Please be aware that **American English speakers tend to use bring everywhere**.  You get sentences like:

- Dad, **can you bring me to the football field**?

Comment: the speaker is asking to be taken to a place where he or she is not. The correct verb here is take:

- Dad, can you **take me t**o the football field?

Bring:

- I asked the waiter to **bring us** a house wine. [toward the speaker]

Take:

- I asked the waiter to take them a house wine. [away from the speaker, the "them" are not sitting in the same place as the speaker]