# "take my phone with me" or "carry my phone with me" or "bring my phone with me"?

Tags: word-usage

Tell me please which sentences sounds more natural.

> I always **take** my phone **with** me as I may need to make a phone call at any moment.
>
> I always **carry** my phone **with** me as I may need to make a phone call at any moment.
>
> I always **bring** my phone **with** me as I may need to make a phone call at any moment.

What I am trying to say is that I always have my phone with me. Is there any difference between the sentences? Are all of them natural sounding?

Comment: As a native English speaker, they all sound pretty natural to me and all convey the same idea.

Comment: There are a couple of existing questions on take vs bring: [1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229558/are-the-verbs-take-and-bring-considered-antonyms), [2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176292/difference-between-take-and-bring). Carry and bring are similar, at least for a phone (not for a person).

Answer (score 1):

The differences are subtle, people will understand all three variations.

"Bring my phone with me" is not quite right. You bring something for the benefit of others. I visit a friend who always has things in his home that need repairing, so I bring my toolbox. I went to a friends birthday and brought my camera to take photos for everyone.

"Carry" means you always carry the phone, even at home. "Take" means you always carry your phone when you go somewhere. In practice, very very little difference.

Answer (score 0):

All are fine.  Using "carry" would be a little less common. I would probably say, "I always take my phone with me, since I might need to make a call at any minute."  That would be slightly less formal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming to my house you might *bring* your phone with you. When you are leaving you *take* your phone with you. Usually you will do these things by *carrying* your phone with you (in a pocket or handbag) rather than by leaving it in your car.

I most often hear *take*; I take my phone from wherever I have just been to wherever I am going.