# "Pick me up and bring me" vs "carry me" vs other form

Tags: grammaticality, spoken-english

Let's say my child wants me to pick him up and carry him to his room, what should he say?
What a native English speaker would say in this situation?

1. "Daddy pick me up and bring me to my room"
2. "Daddy carry me to my room"
3. "Daddy bring me to my room" or another more natural sentence...

Comment: Strictly speaking, you bring something to where the speaker is, so (2) is the correct one (though, as James says, a small child might get it wrong).

Comment: @KateBunting thanks, i thought *"carry me"* would sound strange (not natural) in this situation because I'm not carrying him like a luggage/bag, but I pick him up and hold him close to me.

Comment: Carry can mean "carry a child" by picking them up a holding them close.

Comment: You can carry someone/something in your arms as well as by a handle.

Comment: Note: 'bring' & 'take' are often difficult for ESL learners. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176292/difference-between-take-and-bring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any of those seem quite reasonable expressions for a child to say. It is quite common for "bring" and "take" to be used quite flexibly by children.  An adult should probably use "take me to my room".

Childish speech is an interesting avenue of academic study in grammar, but not a principle concern of language learners. An adult should not normally be trying to speak like a child (unless writing fiction), and a child can say whatever gets the job done.

Comment: Sorry I rephrased my question, I wasn't interested in how a child would say it, but I was just describing the situation: a child and his daddy. I was interested to know the grammatically correct way to say it, but also the more natural one. According to your answer I woud say the correct way to say it is *"daddy pick me up and take me to my room"*. I thought anyway there was a more natural way to say it maybe with a phrasal verb.

Comment: My answer remains.  All are perfectly acceptable, though the use of "bring" might be criticised in a test situation.